# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rasa.nlu.components'

Tags: rasa

I am using Python `3.8.13` on Ubuntu Operating System

I am facing this error - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rasa.nlu.components'

```
>>>from rasa.nlu.components import Component
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rasa.nlu.components'
```

RASA install configurations:

```
Rasa Version      :         3.3.1
Minimum Compatible Version: 3.0.0
Rasa SDK Version  :         3.3.0
Python Version    :         3.8.13
Operating System  :         Linux-5.14.0-1048-oem-x86_64-with-glibc2.17
Python Path       :         /home/user/miniconda3/envs/rasa/bin/python
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: When do you face this error? When training or initializing?

Comment: During initialization